# NSXMLParserDelegate memory issues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I'm running my app through Instruments, and every time the following setup causes a memory leak (apparently). I can't see an issue with this.

WeatherParser.h:

```
...
{
    NSMutableDictionary *results;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *results;
```

WeatherParser.m

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{    
    self.results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

...add values to results

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.results = nil;
    [self.results release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Would greatly appreciate any observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap these around to read:

```
[self.results release]; 
self.results = nil;
```

you were calling the release on the nil object not on the results array.